# Vector field is holomorphic iff dual $1$-form is holomorphic with respect to a Hermitian metric

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,J)$ be a complex manifold and $g$ be a Riemannian metric satisfying $g(J \cdot, J \cdot) = g(\cdot, \cdot)$. Let $\xi$ be a vector field and $\eta$ be the $1$-form defined by $\eta(X) := g(\xi, X)$.

Is it true that if $\bar\partial \eta = 0$ then $\xi$ is a holomorphic vector field, i.e. $L_\xi J = 0$? If not in general, what about if $M$ is compact Kähler? What about the converse?

About the converse, if $\xi$ is holomorphic then $d\eta$ is a $(1,1)$-form; if $M$ is Kähler, by the global $\partial \bar\partial$-lemma we can write $d\eta = dd^c u$ for some function $u$, so $\eta - d^c u$ is closed, so by Hodge decomposition $\eta - d^c u = df + \eta_0$ where $\eta_0$ is $\Delta$-harmonic, so $\Delta^\partial$-harmonic (because we're Kähler), so, since $M$ is compact $\partial \eta_0 = 0$. So
$$\partial \eta = \partial d^c u + \partial(\partial + \bar\partial)f = 
i\partial (\bar\partial - \partial)u + \partial\bar\partial f =\partial\bar\partial (iu-f) 
$$
and on the other hand $d\eta = dd^c u$ because $d\eta_0 = 0$ and so $d \eta - \partial\eta = \bar\partial\eta = \partial\bar\partial f$. I don't know if there is any conclusion that can be drawn from here.

For the initial question, I don't know what would be an approach in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The form $\eta$ is holomorphic if and only if $\eta(X)$ is a holomorphic function for every holomorphic tangent field $X$. If $X$ is such a field we have
$$
\bar\partial \eta(X)
= \bar\partial g(X, \overline \xi)
= g(X, \overline{D' \xi}),
$$
where $D'$ is the $(1,0)$-part of the Chern connection of $g$. (I've assumed here that $g$ is linear in its first variable and antilinear in the second, so that $\eta$ is linear.) It follows that $\bar\partial \eta = 0$ if and only if $D'\xi = 0$. I don't think it necessarily follows that $\bar\partial \xi = 0$.

Suppose in fact that $M$ admits a flat Chern connection $D$ and let $\xi$ be a parallel holomorphic tangent field. If $f$ is a nonconstant holomorphic function, then
$$
D'(\overline f \cdot \xi)
= \partial \overline f \otimes \xi + \overline f D' \xi = 0
$$
but $\bar\partial(\overline f \xi) = \overline{\partial f} \otimes \xi \not= 0$, and $\overline f \xi$ should make for a holomorphic form $\eta$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what $\bar\partial$ is. I know $TM$ admits a holomorphic structure $\bar\partial: \Omega^{p,q}(M) \otimes TM \rightarrow \Omega^{p,q+1}(M) \otimes TM$ and that for $p=q=0$ this is the $(0,1)$-part of the Chern connection and  is given as $\partial Y(X) = 1/2 (\nabla_XY + J\nabla_{JX} Y - J (\nabla_Y J)X $. If this is the $\bar\partial$, shouldn't the condition that $\xi$ is holomorphic be $\bar\partial^2 \xi = 0$? Also, it's not clear to me why this condition would be equivalent to $L_\xi J = 0$ i.e. why holom. as a section of $TM$ is the same as holom. as a real v.f.

Comment: Sorry, $\bar\partial^2 = 0$ automatically. Also I meant $\bar \partial (X) = 1/2 (\nabla_X \xi + J \nabla_{JX} \xi - J (\nabla_\xi J)X )$. But $(L_\xi J)(X) = [\xi, JX] - J[\xi, X] = \nabla_\xi (JX) - \nabla_{JX} \xi - J\nabla_\xi X + J\nabla_X \xi$. On Kähler they are equivalent, since $\nabla J = 0$. So it seems that $\bar\partial \xi = 0$ is equivalent with $L_\xi J = 0$ iff $M$ is Kähler, if I'm not missing something, right?

Comment: I honestly don't know enough about the real point of view to answer that. Looking at Ballmann, yes $\bar\partial \xi = 0$ is equivalent to $L_\xi J = 0$ for metrics with torsion-free connections (so Kahler metrics). I'd assume that there are non-Kahler metrics for which we'd have $\xi$ holomorphic but $L_\xi J \not=0$. The thing is that being holomorphic is defined without reference to a metric structure, we only need the complex structure for that.

Comment: But more hand-wavingly, the holomorphic tangent and cotangent bundles are... holomorphic. The metric is usually only smooth (except when it is flat), and thus only gives a smooth isomorphism $\overline T_X \to T_X^*$, which does not in general send holomorphic sections to holomorphic sections. One therefore expects the answer to the question as it was phrased (in terms of holomorphic sections) to be "no".